# Fetch logs for killed docker container in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

A simplified version of the code

```
trap 'rm /tmp/not_done; echo "trap command got executed"; sleep 10' SIGTERM

wait_sigterm() {

  touch /tmp/not_done
  while [ -f /tmp/not_done ]
  do
      sleep 60 &
      wait $!  
  done
}

wait_sigterm
```

How can I make sure trap command got executed?

One way would be if I can get access to the logs of the killed container and check for my echo message.

I tried getting the logs (kubectl -n namespace-name logs pod-name container-name) in a while loop, so that I would be able to pick the last written logs till the container is alive.

But the echo message was not present.
My guess is logs are not written once we kill the container or maybe something else.
Is there any way I can get the logs of a killed container or test the above scenario?

Answer (score 5):

**Approach 1**

If you want to check out the logs of the previously terminated container from pod POD_NAME.
You can use the following command with -p flag

```
kubectl logs POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME -p
```

You can get further information such as **options and flags**  with the following command

```
kubectl logs --help
```

**Approach 2**

another approach to determine the termination message is in the Status field of Pod object.

`kubectl get pod $POD_NAME -o yaml`

check the field **lastState** of **containerStatuses**:

```
status:
  conditions:

  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: 
    image: registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7:latest
    imageID:
    lastState: {}

    state:
      running:
```

Here is more detail [reading-a-termination-message](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message)

Comment: Still after running the above command I was not able to find the echo message("trap command got executed"). According to my understanding maybe docker doesn't collect the logs as soon as we kill/stop the container.Is there any way to see trap command got executed?

Comment: Docker collect logs from the stdout & stderr,  It seems your output of echo command is in the stdout. You can go inside and check where is the logs streaming to

Comment: Hi, Here is https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/determine-reason-pod-failure/#writing-and-reading-a-termination-message  might be helpful

Answer (score 4):

To determine last termination state of containers' pod, you can fetch it with `-o go-template`:

```
kubectl get pod $POD-NAME -n $NAMESPACE -o go-template='{{range.status.containerStatuses}}{{"Container Name: "}}{{.name}}{{"\r\nLastState: "}}{{.lastState}}{{end}}'
```

For example, on container termination due to low memory on my Jenkins node, I got:

> Container Name: jenkins-node
>
> LastState: map[terminated:map[containerID:docker://ac5df0fb9e213839758f9e7ecd77a73e80a1f59309d725145ca192d7350f0014
> exitCode:137 finishedAt:2020-11-25T06:50:50Z reason:OOMKilled
> startedAt:2020-11-18T13:58:49Z]]

See other options here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/list-all-running-container-images/#list-container-images-using-a-go-template-instead-of-jsonpath

Comment: Brilliant answer!